# Получить ссылку на класс из ссылки на метод

Tags: python

У меня есть код:

```py
class MyClass:
    def my_method(self):
        passs

method = MyClass.my_method
```

Могу я как-то из переменной `method` получить ссылку на класс `MyClass`?

Comment: В Python 2 можете (`method.im_class`), в Python 3 эту возможность удалили

Comment: @andreymal через специальные хуки (вроде `method.__code__`) тоже нельзя?

Comment: Насколько мне известно — нет, `__code__` не хранит свой контекст. Контекст есть в `method.__globals__`, однако там будут все классы и найти правильный получится разве что полным перебором всех методов во всех классах. Есть ещё название класса в строке `method.__qualname__`, но опять же никто не гарантирует что оно там правильное

Comment: А ещё технически возможно запихнуть один и тот же метод в несколько разных классов, что делает задачу вообще максимально весёлой :)

Comment: Судя по всему, Гвидо чем-то мешала эта возможность :) Посмотрел модуль `inspect`, он тоже не умеет такое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно при помощи `inspect`.

```
class MyClass:
    A = 111
    def my_method(self):
        pass

method = MyClass.my_method

import inspect
def get_class(method):
    return getattr(inspect.getmodule(method), 
                   method.__qualname__.split('.<locals>', 1)[0].rsplit('.', 1)[0],
                   None)
                       
cls = get_class(method)                       
print(cls, cls.A)
```

```
<class '__main__.MyClass'> 111
```

На английском SO есть не один тред на эту тему. [Вот, к примеру](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589311/get-defining-class-of-unbound-method-object-in-python-3/25959545#25959545).

Comment: Есть много пограничных случаев, при которых это может не работать

Comment: Да. Но конкретно для данного примера это применимо.